# How to find specific month with the specific condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve a mysql task. Below is the objective of my sql query
"Show all months of the year 2017 that the number of customers applying for
loans are 20% higher than the monthly average number of customers of the year."

I'm trying to solve this task with this query :

```
SELECT monthname(created_date) 
FROM customers 
WHERE year(2017) 
  and count(customer_id) >= 0.2 * avg(count(costumers))
```

I have tried to search in stackoverflow answers but none of those can answer my problem.

Below is the table structure :

[image]

I am using MYSQL 8

This is my SQL DUMP :

> ```
> -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.17, for Win64 (x86_64)
> --
> -- Host: localhost    Database: marketplace
> -- ------------------------------------------------------
> -- Server version 8.0.17
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> /*!50503 SET NAMES utf8 */;
> /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
> /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
> /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
> /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
> /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `banks`
> --
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `banks`;
> /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
> /*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
> CREATE TABLE `banks` (
>   `bank_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `bank_name` tinytext,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`bank_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
> /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
>
> --
> -- Dumping data for table `banks`
> --
>
> LOCK TABLES `banks` WRITE;
> /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `banks` DISABLE KEYS */;
> INSERT INTO `banks` VALUES (1,'HSBC'),(2,'Ocean Bank'),(3,'BCA'),(4,'BRI'),(5,'BNI'),(6,'BTPN'),(7,'Bank Keadilan');
> /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `banks` ENABLE KEYS */;
> UNLOCK TABLES;
>
> --
> -- Table structure for table `customers`
> --
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customers`;
> /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
> /*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
> CREATE TABLE `customers` (
>   `costumer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `customer_name` text,
>   `customer_age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `estimated_risk_level` text,
>   `source` text,
>   `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`costumer_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
> /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
>
> --
> -- Dumping data for table `customers`
> --
>
> LOCK TABLES `customers` WRITE;
> /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customers` DISABLE KEYS */;
> INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (1,'najib',45,'high','facebook','2019-08-13
> ```
>
> 09:27:52'),(2,'ridho',19,'low','google','2019-08-13
>   09:27:52'),(3,'ujang',25,'high','facebook','2019-08-13
>   09:27:52'),(4,'nadya',23,'medium','instagram','2019-08-13
>   09:27:52'),(5,'uli',22,'medium','google','2019-08-13
>   09:27:52'),(6,'syahputra',35,'low','google','2019-08-13 09:27:52');
>       /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customers` ENABLE KEYS */;
>       UNLOCK TABLES;
>
> ```
> --
> -- Table structure for table `leads`
> --
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `leads`;
> /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
> /*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
> CREATE TABLE `leads` (
>   `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `apply_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
> /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
>
> --
> -- Dumping data for table `leads`
> --
>
> LOCK TABLES `leads` WRITE;
> /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `leads` DISABLE KEYS */;
> INSERT INTO `leads` VALUES (1,2,'2019-08-14 09:27:52'),(2,1,'2019-08-14 09:27:52'),(4,6,'2019-08-14
> ```
>
> 09:27:52'),(5,5,'2019-08-14 09:27:52'),(6,4,'2019-08-14 09:27:52');
>       /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `leads` ENABLE KEYS */;
>       UNLOCK TABLES;
>
> ```
> --
> -- Table structure for table `products`
> --
>
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
> /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
> /*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
> CREATE TABLE `products` (
>   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `loan_amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `interest_rate` float DEFAULT NULL,
>   `accepted_risk_level` text,
>   `bank_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
> /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
>
> --
> -- Dumping data for table `products`
> --
>
> LOCK TABLES `products` WRITE;
> /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products` DISABLE KEYS */;
> INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (1,1500,2.5,'low',1,'2019-08-13 09:27:52'),(2,2000,2.5,'high',1,'2019-08-13
> ```
>
> 09:27:52'),(3,1200,5,'high',1,'2019-08-13
>   09:27:52'),(4,2500,2.5,'medium',2,'2019-08-13
>   09:27:52'),(5,1550,5,'medium',2,'2019-08-13 09:27:52');
>       /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products` ENABLE KEYS */;
>       UNLOCK TABLES;
>       /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
>
> ```
> /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
> /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
> /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
> /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
> /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
>
> -- Dump completed on 2019-08-13 22:31:35
> ```

Comment: Why you have the loans on the customer table?

Comment: Customers table doesnt have `created_date`  are you sure you don't have a `Loans` table

Comment: Sorry, it actually has created_date but I am forget to put it in the image.

Comment: Even with `created_date`,  that doesn't look like loan apply info.

Comment: Ok wait I will put my entire schema in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c62414d7ab4f464d5aa37b461ca9113&hide=1)

First step check how many customers apply for a loan each month:

```
SELECT COUNT(customer_id) as monthly_count
FROM leads
WHERE year(apply_date) = 2019
GROUP BY MONTH(apply_date);

monthly_count
1
4
```

Now you can calculate the avg of application for month:

```
SELECT AVG(monthly_count) as loans_avg
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(customer_id) as monthly_count
    FROM leads
    WHERE year(apply_date) = 2019
    GROUP BY MONTH(apply_date)
) t

loans_avg
2.5000
```

Now you can compare the monthly count with the average:

```
WITH monthly_avg as  (
    SELECT AVG(monthly_count) as loans_avg
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(customer_id) as monthly_count
        FROM leads
        WHERE year(apply_date) = 2019
        GROUP BY MONTH(apply_date)
        ) t
)
SELECT monthname(apply_date), COUNT(customer_id) as monthly_count
FROM leads
WHERE year(apply_date) = 2019
GROUP BY monthname(apply_date)
HAVING monthly_count > (SELECT 1.2 * loans_avg
                        FROM monthly_avg)


monthname(apply_date)   monthly_count
July                       4
```

In this case only July is above the `1.2 * average`

Comment: I want to make a monthly average number of customers of the year.
Then I want to show the month which having number of customers applying for loans are 20% higher than the monthly average number of customers of the year.

Comment: Thank you so much.. you are the legend.

Comment: Check updated answer. Note I change your data to have two different months